# Folders and files of a .php script

Tags: php

1) Let's say I write an app starting from index.php or admin/index.php (admin panel). (Maybe I should start writing code in some other place, or it depends, I am not sure; if this could be answered this could be good too). I write code within any of these index.php files and what is the thinking beind starting another .php file. When do I decide that, ok, this is no longer for index.php and I need to create another file. What could be the theory behind this?

Like, lets say we have an application with /foleder1 with 20 .php files in there and one index.php file outside of this folder. What could be the thinking about this, why would the developer create the 20 separate files in this folder and so on. Or another app with 10 folders and 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110 in them consecutively. What could be the thinking about this? I mean, ok this folder has 110 files, that one 100, the developer must have made it because of this or this. I mean, what could be the theory about this?

2) Can the process of creating new script files or folders be related to the html menu structure of the site. Like we have menu A, B, C, D, E, F, G in the html and we would probably create something like a.php, b.php, c.php, d.php, e.php, f.php, g.php for these? Or separate folders maybe in some cases but this division would be made.

I am basically trying to get an understanding on how this works. I see it as all files having the same relation to a database (lets say just one table with columns). We can code the connection into any file, do certain things within any file and so on. But what is the process of dividing any application into folders and files? What could be the theory behind it? Where to learn that? (Just keep writing code and you fill figure it out / understand...).

This seems like the very #1 thing for now that I would need to understand to get the whole "big picture" of this and all would be easier after that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1)*** The answer is short.**A developer is not a robot or computer!**
The developer needs sorted files and data to edit, debug or remove them.Yes, You can merge all those files together but what if some day you need to modify the session part or database connection part? Can you pass through all those files and edit them one by one? How much time does that take?

***2)*** I think this is same as first question but a little different.

For example: You have a website with 50 php pages that all of them needs to be connected to database.Which one is easier and more efficient?

**1**-Connecting to database in each file

**2**-Write database connection query in one file and then include it in every file you need

Of course, option  2 is better.You save a lot of time,space,etc... and it will reduce the chance of mistake because you write the code only once and if it has any mistakes it should appear on every page so you can fix it by just editing one page.But how about connecting to database in each file? A little typo in a single file can cause many warnings and even dangerous situation!(This was just one sample of having too many files)

And again we can say the first question's answer for second question.Developer should be comfortable with codes and he should easily access to the source of any part of the script(For example menus).

**Conclusion:**

Although having separated files helps the developer concentrate on each part more and better, it's just an option! The developer might want to have all those 50 files together in just 1 file and just do the functions in other pages!

I hope I answered your questions in the way you wanted :)

Comment: Sorry, but I dont get that yet. I know that it is possible for anything to work from just one file and I do understand that this is for convenience, division and so on. Is this aribtrary? The same script can be written in different ways (folders and files)? But what could be an explanable theory of creating a new folder and file? I know that all functions can go to one file, one class per file for oop, and database connection in one file and include that. But why do we go and create a.php, then b.php, c.php and so on (after index.php lets say)?

Comment: What would be the colsest thing to explain that. Like a separe functionality of a script maybe like video_import.php, pic_import.php. I would not do these two in the same file. So I develop the whole video import in video_import.php... Anything other than that? For large app I know that I do the html/css first, then I do the database columns (lets assume just one database) and then I write code in the files which can be in folders too. So I would need to understand this layer of creating an app. I dont get that yet...

Comment: As I said above it's just optional and for feeling more comfortable.But imagine Youtube that has parts like importing video and importing thumbnail has a problem or needs an update.Then one group works on Thumbnail section and the other one works on video section.These 2 groups Cannot work together because the programmers need to change the codes every second and if those two were merged, it might result to  HUGE mistakes Because the ((thumbnail section programmer)) may have no idea about the video section and he just wants to do what he has to!

Comment: Maybe I would figure out the url structure of a script and base it on that? Maybe this is what I dont understand. Is the process of creating folders and files preceded by something else (other decissions)? I MEAN - Can it be said, you look at something like /admin in html/css (what you have there) and you create your folders and files based on that. And also the url structure of the script would come before that (the decission about creating folders and files)?

Comment: @gs3 Of course it can have some structure and other URLs are based on that but there is no limitation! You don't have to do that! The structure just organizes the project's files and who hates tidyness? :D. Organizing is what you do before you do something, so that when you do it, it is not all mixed up!

Comment: Would I rather add new files as I go or do I design it all up front and I write after that? I am thinking that this can be based of the html of the admin (what is there) and it could be also the urls of the site (like if I am planning to have a separate url for something I would create a separate file). I have a feeling that this can be narrowed down to certain rules and explained.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/k81id8 - This is the /admin of a pic gallery script. How can I get to the division like this, when I would be writing my own script? Is this "as I go" or is this based off something else (like html of the admin panel, or the url structure of the site)?

Comment: @gs3 In a nutshell, each file which is separated should do something different.you cannot or it's better to say you shouldn't separate the **database connection file** into 2 parts and then add them together using include.You can achieve this type of organizing by just going ahead and once you will notice that everything is being messed up and you need to make it separated so you can easily recognize each file's duty by just reading the file name.This type of organizing doesn't depend on HTML of the admin panel.Actually The panel should be suitable for this type of sorting.

Comment: For example the admin panel can have several parts like **Add user** or **New Topic**. In this case you can put both functions and html of creating new topic in the **New Topic** page in a file called **Admin/New_topic,php** But you can also put the functions in a file called **Admin/New_Topic_functions.php** and include the functions in the panel page.This is completely optional and depends on how you like to write your code!

Comment: Ok. Separate functionalites, it is up to me. Not really based on anything as Step 1 and 2 (or more) of a design process. And this is arbitrary, exactly the same script can be laid out into 50 files or 70 files if I want to have more separation there... And I do it as I go? Not up front? And also, start like index.php or anywhere I want is ok?

Comment: I am in the chat room now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer you are looking for is. Separation of concerns(SoC), Architectures, Design patterns.
You will learn it in time, but if you want to work together well with other developers you should learn or use what everyone is using e.g MVC, Hexagonal, etc.

The way you can learn those things is to start using or playing with some of the frameworks out there like Symfony, Laravel. And I will suggest you make your own framework so you can get a better grasp of it(Just for learning porpuses). And of course, read some books about architecture.